# How can I use alternative android emulators if I'm developing a mobile app with Cordova?

Tags: android, cordova, virtualization

There are many examples of questions about how to speed up the android emulator.  Here's an example: [Why is the Android emulator so slow? How can we speed up the Android emulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554099/why-is-the-android-emulator-so-slow-how-we-can-speed-up-the-android-emulator)  Some of the solutions are, "Use a different emulator".  But, can cordova be configured to use these different emulators?  If so, where do I configure this?  By default, cordova is looking for an AVD (android virtualization device).

Comment: Cordova is just running on top of a Java WebView, in other words, it's run like any other Android project. You just need to follow the advice in that thread you linked to. There is not a single change you need to do.

Answer (score 1):

Install [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com) then run:

```
cordova run android
```

Cordova recognizes Genymotion as a device not an emulator.